# TinyMCE: Disable focus to toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce, tinymce-4

How can I disable "Focus to toolbar" in TinyMCE?

Explanation: 
If I press Alt+F10 in TinyMCE, a white square appears around a button on the toolbar. Then I can move it among the toolbar buttons with the arrow keys, and activate a button by pressing space.
This white square also appears sometimes "by itself". For example, If I press the image button (where I display a file selection box), and then press Esc.

Is there a way to make sure this white square does not appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable focus to the buttons on the toolbar, I execute in the editor init callback function the following command:

```
init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
            $("[tabindex='-1']").removeAttr("tabindex"); // disable toolbar focus               
        }
```

Probably removing the tabindex could have been done a little more selectively and elegantly, but it works fine for me.